# routingError became GRAPH_DISCONNECTED all of a sudden

Tags: android, here-api

So I am one of several developers developing a GPS-app with the help of HERE SDK for Android.

This is a project that has been in the making for some time and it has been a somewhat smooth ride, until yesterday.
We have a couple of tablets to test our app with, and yesterday when building on the Samsung Galaxy Tab A(2016) the routing always gave us "GRAPH_DISCONNECTED" as an answer.

It doesn't matter what route I try. From current location. From a set location. The destination doesn't matter either.

So we have a CoreRouter.Listener that overrides the onCalculateRouteFinished-method and no matter what I do routingError seems to beceome GRAPH_DISCONNECTED.

I have tried to uninstall the app and install it again. Same result.
I have tried deleting the cache for the app. Same result.

The weird part? It has been working on the tablet for well over a year.
And if we use any other tablet, like the Xperia z4 tablet there is no problem with the routing.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so problem found!

Apparently, we had the wrong settings for the vehicle. It was too big to go from the positions we tried with, and that's why HERE couldn't make a valid route.

The strange part is that this route has worked with those vehicle settings before. So some construction must have come up all of a sudden that stopped me from making the same route.